# Operator Overloading working but giving stack overflow and crashing in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stack-overflow

I wrote this Node class and = operator overload function and this is the only way I could get it to compile and run but it just overflows and bomb my program. Can someone please fix it so it works. I don't have a lot of experience with overloading operator in C++. I just want to set a Node object equal to another Node object. Thanks in advance!

```
class Node
{ 
   public:
      Node();
      int y;
      Node& operator=(const Node& n);
};

Node::Node(){ y = -1; }
Node& Node::operator=(const Node& n) { return *this = n; }
```

.

```
Build issues:
1>c:\users\aaron mckellar\documents\school stuff\cs445\test\test\main.cpp(57) : warning C4717: 'Node::operator=' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
1>Linking...
1>LINK : C:\Users\Aaron McKellar\Documents\School Stuff\CS445\Test\Debug\Test.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
```

Comment: Do you know what the assignment operator is for?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I get it now. I knew it was something simple I just have little experience overloading. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your `operator=` you need to do the work of setting the member variables equal to the passed in Node's value.

```
Node& Node::operator=(const Node& n) 
{ 
    y = n.y;
    return *this; 
}
```

A corresponding example of what you did in English: The definition of a dog is a dog.   Instead of saying the definition of a dog is a domesticated form of the wolf, a member of the Canidae family of the order Carnivora.

Comment: He doesn't need to define operator= at all. Your definition is the same as the default definition.

Comment: I assume he posted a simplified example of what he wants to do.

Comment: You forgot to check for self assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite recursion because *this = n is calling Node::operator=() (because this is a Node).  The usual behaviour of the assignment operator is like a copy constructor, but you must check for self assignment.  See: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/assignment-operators.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the offending function. C++ defines a default `operator=` for you. The function is "there" in every sense: you can get a pointer to it, etc. However, if you add an overload, the default goes away completely, and using `=` within it causes recursion.

If you actually have additional functionality to add to `operator=`, you will have to implement the default functionality as well, yourself, ie `y = n.y;`. Your overload kills the default `=` so `*this=n` has nothing to do except call itself.

If you have a lot of data members, one alternative would be to declare a class just to use its default `operator=`:

```
struct Node_data { // "POD" struct for just data, no methods
    int q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z; // rough example ;v)
};

class Node : public Node_data {
    …
    Node & Node::operator=( const Node &n ) {
        Node_data::operator=( n ); // compiler-generated func
        cout << "operator= called" << endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `Node::operator=(const Node& n)` contains `return *this = n;`. `return *this = n;` calls `operator=` because you are using = on an instance of your class and another instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Your overloaded operator is what is called for code that looks like this:

```
node = someothernode;
```

Since '*nodeptr' is equivalent to 'node', you have created an operator which calls itself.